# displaying a collection in symfony 2 form with data from a foreign table

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, twig, symfony-forms

I'm a newbie at symfony and I can't find a solution for my problem regarding displaying a form the correct way.

I've got three tables: activities, presences and persons

```
desc activities;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stop     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| activity | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| event_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc presences;
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| activity_id | int(11)                                      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| person_id   | int(11)                                      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| status      | enum('afwezig','aanwezig','verontschuldigd') | NO   | PRI | afwezig |       |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

desc persons;
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id            | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| firstname     | varchar(20)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| name          | varchar(30)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
```

+---------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

I have created 2 formtypes 
One for the activities

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'start',
                'datetime',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Start'

                )
            )
            ->add(
                'stop',
                'datetime',
                array(
                    'label' => 'Stop'

                )
            )
            ->add('activity', 'text', array('label' => 'Naam'))
            ->add('location', 'text', array('label' => 'Locatie'))
            ->add(
                'presences',
                'collection',
                array(
                    'type' => new PresencesType()
                )
            )
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Aanpassen'));
    }
```

And one for displaying the presences of a certain activity

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add(
                    'persons',
                    'entity',
                    array(
                        'class' => 'KHOSAdminBundle:Persons',
                        'label' => false,
                        'property' => 'fullname',
                        'read_only' => true,
                        'disabled' =>true
                    )
                )
                ->add(
                    'status',
                    'choice',
                    array(
                        'label' => false,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'choices' => array(
                            'afwezig' => 'afwezig',
                            'aanwezig' => 'aanwezig',
                            'verontschuldigd' => 'verontschuldigd'
                        )
                    )
                );
        }
```

using twig I can render this so it shows the details of the activity and below a list of presences.

```
{% for presence in form_activity.presences %}
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
         {{ form_row(presence.persons) }}
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          {{ form_row(presence.status, { 'style': 'inline' }) }}
       </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

All persons are dropdown's however and it takes ages to load.
But I don't want that

I just want the details of the activity and below a list of all persons with there status as a radiobutton

```
Start: <<inputfield>>   Stop: <<inputfield>>
location: <<inputfield>>

firstname1 name1 : O afwezig  O  aanwezig  O verontschuldigd
firstname2 name2 : O afwezig  O  aanwezig  O verontschuldigd
firstname3 name3 : O afwezig  O  aanwezig  O verontschuldigd
firstname4 name4 : O afwezig  O  aanwezig  O verontschuldigd
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: As a start, I'm wondering why each Presence instances have many Persons? By looking at the expected form, it seems that each Presence has one and only one Person, am I right? It takes ages to load, because each Presence instance will load all the Persons from the database to create the choice list (although some cache mecanism should allow performing the db query only once normally, but I haven't looked at the EntityType code for a while).

Comment: It's correct: Every instance of presence can have only one person, but every person can have multiple presences.
I will change the entity so it is a onetoone relationschip. Do you maybe also know how I can create a list as in my example?

Comment: Ok I think I understand the confusion, `entity` field type is a sub type of `choice`, it's not aimed to render a single entity. I'll arrange a solution I can present to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've suggested in comment, you should use a custom type for presence that does not use an `entity` field (you do not want to be able to edit the Person contained inside a Presence instance anyway, meaning you don't want a firstName and lastName fields).

Here's the php part:

```
<?php

namespace Demo {
    class Activity
    {
        protected $id;
        protected $start;
        protected $stop;

        /** @var Presence[] */
        protected $presences = [];

        // ...
    }

    class Presence {
        /** @var Activity */
        protected $activity;
        /** @var Person */
        protected $person;
        protected $status;

        // ...
    }

    class Person {
        protected $firstName;
        protected $lastName;
        /** @var Presence[] */
        protected $presences;

        // ...
    }

    class ActivityType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('start')
                ->add('stop')
                ->add('location')
                ->add('presences', 'collection', [
                    'type' => new PresenceType(),
                ])
            ;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'activity';
        }
    }

    class PresenceType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('status', 'choice', [
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'choices' => [
                        'afwezig' => 'afwezig',
                        'aanwezig' => 'aanwezig',
                        'verontschuldigd' => 'verontschuldigd'
                    ]
                ])
            ;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'presence';
        }
    }
}
```

And the twig form theme (it may requires some tweaking to actually work, but the idea is to define how a presence form view is rendered when you call form_row(form) and form is PresenceType view instance):

```
{% block presence_row %}
    {{ form.vars.data.user.firstName }} {{ form.vars.data.user.lastName }} {{ form_widget(form) }}
    # form.vars.data contains the Presence instance
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I use the form theme to display the firstName and lastName of Person, and I haven't added it in my PresenceType class, that's because I don't need a firstName and lastName input fields.

Comment: I understand the main what you're saying but I can't get it to work. I can't get the firstname and the lastname in the form, and the form is of PresenceTypeView instance. 
The error is always in the kind of

Comment: I understand the main what you're saying but I can't get it to work. I can't get the firstname and the lastname in the form, and the form is of PresenceTypeView instance. 
The error is always in the kind of:

Method "......" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in....

my twig
 {{ form_start(form_activity) }}
 {{ form_row(form_activity.start) }}
.....
 {{ form_row(form_activity.save) }}

{% for presence in form_activity.presences %}
{{ presence.user.data.firstname }}
                                        
{{ form_row(presence.status) }}

 {% endfor %}

Comment: `presence.user` won't work because PresenceType hasn't got a `user` field. You have to use the underlying Presence object: `presence.vars.data.user.firstName`, (presence.vars.data is the Presence object).

Comment: Gildas, You have just made my day. Thank you very much